# PhantomJS unexpectedly exits on Selenium : WebDriverException with status code 127

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, virtualenv

I am using a global PhantomJS on my Mac OS X for multiple Javascript and Python selenium projects. For the first time, I set up a virtual environnement using virtualenv :

```
virtualenv Python3.5 Path/To/MyEnvironnement
```

Then :

```
Path/To/MyEnvironnement
. bin/activate
which phantomjs
```

... returns my global selenium : /Users/Me/.npm-packages/bin/phantomjs

But every time I call :

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'/Users/Me/.npm-packages/bin/phantomjs')
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Path/To/MyEnvironnement/script/spider/crawl/Urls.py", line 194, in <module>
init_driver()
File "/Path/To/MyEnvironnement/script/spider/crawl/Urls.py", line 29, in init_driver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'/Users/Me/.npm-packages/bin/phantomjs')
File "/Path/To/MyEnvironnement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/Path/To/MyEnvironnement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
File "/Path/To/MyEnvironnement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 99, in assert_process_still_running
% (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Users/Me/.npm-packages/bin/phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

It's been 24 hours since I first got this issue, and I read virtually all posts that could refer to it.

I tried, without success, to create a nodeenv inside my virtualenv : [running phantomjs inside python virtualenv for selenium project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087878/running-phantomjs-inside-python-virtualenv-for-selenium-project)

Comment: I tried running the code using my global Python 3.5 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess its too late, but for future reference I've solved this issue by:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig
```

The answer was found here:

[Trouble connecting to phantomJs webdriver using python and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338609/trouble-connecting-to-phantomjs-webdriver-using-python-and-selenium)

Comment: Is there a solution for Windows 10?