# Selenium exits with errors (chromewebdriver)

Tags: python, selenium

When I run my script (which tests the subscribe feature on my friends website)
It exits with this error:

```
  File "subtest.py", line 3, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
% (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

I should also mention that I am using python2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar error `Status code was: 127` while, I tried to run selenium on my desktop. Installed the following package according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43168960/3083094)
 solved my issue.

```
sudo apt install libfontconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running the chromedriver binary by itself, in the case of a missing library like @Joao Vitorino has mentioned it will log.

In my case I needed to install `libgconf-2-4` on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: same with me, on lubuntu 17.10 - this was the solution

Answer (score 0):

*Status code was: 127*

Means command not found or a dependency library was not found